# How do you detect the collision of two sprites that are on different layers with LimeJS?

Tags: javascript, game-engine, limejs

I have one sprite on the main scene and another on a positioned layer (with the later being on the main scene too).

I want to detect collisions between them but the boundingBox() function of the sprite on the layer is offsetting by the position of the parent layer.

How do I detect a collision between the two sprites?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
if(goog.math.Box.intersects(this.sprite1.getBoundingBox(), sprite2.getBoundingBox())){
    //do something...
}
```